# list search obj with index number

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
stations = ['Schagen', 'Heerhugowaard', 'Alkmaar', 'Castricum', 'Zaandam', 'Amsterdam Sloterdijk', 'Amsterdam Centraal', 'Amsterdam Amstel', 'Utrecht Centraal', '’s-Hertogenbosch', 'Eindhoven', 'Weert', 'Roermond', 'Sittard', 'Maastricht']
```

I tried this:

```
print(sations.index[1])
```

I cant find a way to print a list item when I search for the index.

Comment: `list.index` is a function so trying to subscript it won't work. If you are looking to print an item in the list, index the list with `stations[0]`, or, in general, `stations[n]` where `n` in `[0, len(stations-1)]`. If you are looking to get the index for an item use `stations.index('item-name')`.

Comment: Sorry, The question is not clear. Can you explain (in the question) what you want to do?

Comment: You're printing `sations.index[1]`, not `stations.index[1]`.

Comment: thanks it worked i used stations[x] format

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find an object, you can use `index()`. For example

```
index = 0
if "Zaandam" in stations:
    index = stations.index("Zaandam")
print(stations[index])
```

The index of `Zaandam` is being logged to the variable `index` and then it's logged index is being used to `print` itself. The `if` statement is simply a wrapper.